# How to run Gradle as separate process from Gradle?

Tags: process, gradle

I need to run Gradle as separate process from Gradle, in order to avoid problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170510/access-denied-when-gradle-script-is-trying-to-open-cached-artifact-file

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: I suppose that what You need is a tooling API. It enables to run gradle programatically. You can find examples of tooling API under `$GRADLE_HOME/samples/toolingApi` (e.g. `runBuild` project) if You have gradle installed on the file system.

Comment: Is that what You were looking for?